# Basic power: drive 12v LED from 5v Raspberry Pi output — no 12v supply available

Tags: arduino, transistors, raspberry-pi, boost

There are *a lot* of questions on here and elsewhere about this.

The consensus seems to be to use a transistor to switch a power supply — implying that I have a 12v supply available.

Only 5V is available, either coming out of the GPIO pins or directly from the power supply (USB battery in this case).

This is a single LED: seems like it should be possible to directly wire it to the GPIO pins with a component in the middle that raises voltage. (GPIO pins can "safely" provide 16 mA)

It appears that I need a stepup/boost converter, but nobody seems to be discussing that. Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: What kind of 12v led? Datasheet or product page? How much current is needed?

Comment: Several boost converter chips are available. A 5V - 12V converter could be designed. The GPIO pins aren't suitable, you need to use the 5V supply.

Comment: A "12v LED" is something of an oxymoron - it has to be an LED with current limiting resistor or regulator built in. Can you simply find a 5V variant?

Comment: @NickJohnson You're probably right, but the LED is part of a bigger device and I can't rip the LED out.

Comment: @Passerby No information on the LED, other than it "runs at 12VDC" (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9181)

Comment: I've actually worked with those buttons before. There's a resistor in there, and you could fairly trivially open it up and replace it with a smaller value resistor. It'd certainly be simpler than a boost converter!

Comment: Yea, the button is designed to be opened. Read the description and see the third picture. Just swap the resistor. See my edit.

Comment: You both are right. I hadn't looked at it closely, but the LED is easily disassemblable. It seems that 5v LEDs aren't very common, but your suggestion is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need a boost converter on the 5V supply input,  to 12V. You can typically see 85% efficiency. You still want to use the transistor on the RPI output, since it is 3.3v and low current.

Any typical step up or boost converter will work,  considering you keep in mind the minimum regulating load.

Alternatively you can find a boost converter with a 3.3v enable pin, and control it directly from the rpi.

***Edit*** The button that OP linked to can be disassembled by design, to replace parts. An easier solution is to replace the led resistor with one suitable for 5V operation. I'd still advise a transistor setup. If you feel lucky punk, well do you?, then a resistor suitable for a red led at 3.3V 16 mA or less would work directly, with minimal brightness change, but a ten cent transistor to protect the RPI pin is recommended.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this thread as I am doing the same thing with an Arduino. I am fairly new to the whole electronics scene (coming from a software engineering background) but keen to learn. Based on the specs above, would a 120 ohm resistor do the trick (assuming a 5V source, 3.3V forward voltage, 16mA forward current)? Could you also elaborate on the transistor that you recommended to include - why it's a good idea to include the transistor, and what transistor to use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 12 volt LED and only a 5 volt supply you need a boost regulator and a means of activating the LED from a gpio pin. So, look for a suitable boost converter (TI or LT) and then choose a BJT that can be activated by a gpio pin via a resistor. Emitter connects to 0 volts and collector to the LED cathode. Anode to 12 volts and MAKE SURE that the LED will work without a current limiting resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Pi can supply 16mA (ish - drive strength is a poorly controlled parameter) at 5V, energy is conserved. Since Power P = I*V, where I is current and V is voltage, stepping up the voltage means the current supplied to the LED will be lower than the current from the GPIO - *even with 100% converter efficiency*, you'll get 4.4mA max from a 3.3v GPIO. When we also take into account that

- The converter efficiency will be much less than 100%, especially with such a large step from 3.3V to 12V
- 16mA is the current with the GPIO shorted - at this point, the output voltage is actually *zero*, not 3.3V. Any significant current draw will cause some amount of voltage drop

We can see that driving a high power LED from a Pi's GPIO is essentially not a good idea.

**BUT**
 there is a better way!

[image: Example circuit for driving high voltage device with Raspberry Pi]

A DC-DC boost converter (search ebay) can provide 12V from a 5V supply with a reasonable efficiency (typically ~85%). A dedicated 12V supply is better.

The current through the LED is switched on and off by a transistor - a MOSFET is ideal because no current flows into its gate while it is on.

The MOSFET suggested in the diagram will happily pass an amp or two with a 3.3V gate voltage from the GPIO pin, making the LEDs much brighter and avoiding any damage to the Pi.

This type of transistor circuit (just the lower part) is very useful for driving higher voltage loads from a low voltage microcontroller or processor.

Comment: Thanks! This idea was quite clear to me, but thanks for providing part numbers.

Comment: Also, somehow I thought the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins outputted 5v, not 3.3v. Thanks for correcting that.